# Los registros que no se encuentran en una tabla, entonces buscar en otra tabla en SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy intentando buscar los registros de una columna llamada "Alumnos" en una tabla1: si los registros no se encuentran en tabla1 entonces los debería de buscar en tabla2.

Nota: Tabla1 y tabla2 tiene en común esta columna llamada "Alumnos".

El resultado esperado es que me muestre los resultado que se encontraron en tabla1 además de los resultados que busco y encontró en tabla2, pero no sé si esté bien estructurada esta consulta, ¿hay alguna sentencia que se debe implementar?

Tengo el siguiente código SQL:

```
select  Alumnos
  from tabla1
 where Alumnos in (
    select Alumnos
      from tabla1 a 
     where not exists(select Alumnos 
                        from tabla2 b 
                       where a.Alumnos = b.Alumnos)
     group by Alumnos)
```

Comment: @padaleiana  Hola, si es en MySQL, se me paso describir en la etiqueta. Gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como [comentaba](/q/558455/#comment986984_558459) en [la respuesta](/a/558459) de [Julio](/users/304420), en MySQL existe la sentencia `UNION DISTINCT`. Nótese lo que dice la [documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html#union-distinct-all) (énfasis mío):

> Por defecto, las **filas duplicadas se eliminan** de los resultados de `UNION`. La palabra clave opcional `DISTINCT` tiene el **mismo efecto** pero **lo hace explícito**.

Por lo tanto, incluso con `UNION` basta, pero digamos que *por las dudas* se agrega `DISTINCT`.

Entonces, la consulta con `UNION DISTINCT` sería:

```sql
SELECT Alumnos 
FROM tabla1
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT Alumnos 
FROM tabla2
```

Comment: Listo, si funciono .Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Lo cierto es que yo utilizo Teradata, así que espero que esto te sirva a ti también.

Lo que yo haría es hacer un `UNION` buscando en primer lugar los alumnos en la tabla 1 y después en la tabla 2. Entiendo que pueden salir repetidos, por lo que añadiría un `DISTINCT`. El código es el siguiente:

```
SELECT DISTINCT aux.*
FROM(
    SELECT Alumnos FROM tabla1
    UNION
    SELECT Alumnos FROM tabla2
) aux
```

Espero que esto de el resultado por el que preguntabas. Saludos!

Comment: En resumen, primero buscar en tabla1 y luego en tabla2, pero que significa "aux." Por que aux? Me podria decir, Por favor

Comment: En resumen, primero buscar en tabla1 y luego en tabla2, pero que significa "aux." Por que aux? Me podría decir, Por favor

Comment: En MySQL 8.0 existe la sentencia [`UNION DISTINCT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html#union-distinct-all), por lo tanto no es necesario _hacer un select de un select_.

Comment: @Cecyg al menos en Teradata es necesario poner un nombre a esa "tabla" que hemos generado (lo que está entre paréntesis, vaya), en otro caso da error. He puesto "aux" que viene de auxiliar.

Comment: @padaleiana vaya! no tenía idea, muchas gracias!

Comment: @padaleiana  y como usar UNION DISTINCT para obtener el resultado que se espera?

Comment: @Julio , Si entiendo entonces  en este caso "aux " es el nombre de la tabla. Gracias

Comment: @Julio Usando DISTINCT  elimina los registros repetidos?

Comment: @Cecyg sí, entendí que era eso lo que buscabas.

Comment: @Julio así es, el resultado no debe tener registros duplicados y para esto pensaba usar UNIQUE, pero veo que con un DISTINCT se puede solucionar, Gracias